# Philips monitor: "Attention: no video input:

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I'm trying to connect a Philips 223V5LSB monitor to my 4 year old Macbook pro. I am using a VGA-VGA cable combined with a VGA-HDMI adapter.

According to the online manual, the monitor should be compatible with Mac OS X.

My Macbook recognises the monitor and gives me all the usual settings to set up dual screens. Moreover, it correctly identifies the model of the monitor. However, I'm getting an error message "Attention: no video input" on the monitor.

Is there a problem with my hardware, or am I doing something silly?